# Conditional check to add class in javascript template

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How to add class conditionally in javascript template.

```
return 
 '<div class={data == sampleData ? "sample_class": "test_class"}>' + data + '</div>'
```

Comment: Hope this helps.. https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/MWeKXPo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a template literal. If you want to keep it as a string you need to concatenate the value correctly:

```
return '<div class="' + (data == sampleData ? "sample_class": "test_class") + '">' + data + '</div>';
```

Alternatively if you do want to do this as a template literal then you need to use the correct syntax:

```
return `<div class="${(data == sampleData ? "sample_class": "test_class")}">${data}</div>`;
```

Answer (score 1):

use ``` backtics(``) ``` to make templates
and can use `${WRITE JS HERE}`

```js
return `
<div class="${data == sampleData ? "sample_class": "test_class"}">
 ${data}
</div>
`
```